# Endpoint not returning expected data based on NDC package code

Tags: openfda

I recently stumbled upon openFDA and it seems to be the perfect answer for relaying drug brand name information to our users based on a provided NDC code.  The issue I am running into however is that majority of the searches I am doing keep turning up with "No matches found!".  For instance when using NDC 10135-150-01 (ASPIRIN 325MG TAB) in my query it comes up with nothing.  Here is my query (going off of the example demo on the openFDA site):

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=package_ndc:"10135-150-01"&limit=1
```

I believe the above query is correct because I have gotten it to work with other NDC package codes, and I believe the codes are true codes because they come up when googled, so this leads me to believe that either the package_ndc codes stored don't include *every* package code, or there is possibly only base codes of some sort stored?  I'm obviously not an expert in the coding system, so if anyone can point out anything obvious it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openFDA has only the NDC codes that are in the [National Drug Code Directory](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/default.cfm). This particular one -- "10135-150-01" -- isn't there, which is why you are getting no results back.

Comment: Hmmmm okay so it looks like I am going to have to look into the codes we are receiving and why they wouldn't be listed in this directory...thanks for the clarification.